# Is it okay to add an enum to a Jackson annotated class?

Tags: java, enums, jackson

I have added an enum to a Class and the class is annotated with Jackson annotations. I don't want this enum to be considered during serialization or deserialization. Do I need to add any special tags to ignore the enum, like we do @JsonIgnore for methods or variables ?

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "name", "license", "description" })
public class Car {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("license")
    private String license;
    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("license")
    public String getLicense() {
        return license;
    }

    @JsonProperty("license")
    public void setLicense(String license) {
        this.license = license;
    }

    @JsonProperty("description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @JsonProperty("description")
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Type getType() {
        if(this.description.contains("electric")) {
            return Type.ELECTRIC;
        }else if(this.description.contains("diesel")) {
            return Type.DIESEL;
        }else {
            return Type.UNKNOWN;
        }
    }

    public enum Type {
        ELECTRIC, DIESEL, GASOLINE, HYDROGEN, BIOFUEL, UNKNOWN
    }
}
```

Here is some code to use this class. It works fine.

```
public class EnumJsonTester {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\r\n" + 
                "  \"name\": \"Tesla Model S\",\r\n" + 
                "  \"license\": \"1234\",\r\n" + 
                "  \"description\": \"electric powered vehicle.\"\r\n" + 
                "}";
        Car tesla = Utils.jsonToObject(json, Car.class);
        System.out.println("My Car: " + tesla.getType());
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not expert with Java, but a good thing to do before asking the question is to try if that attribute does the job as intended. If not, you have a more solid question. What I mean is that you'll show that you tried it and it failed, instead of just "Give me the response". I suggest you go try it (if you didn't yet).

Comment: Do you mean to add an inner enum oder an enum property? If you want the second, @JsonIgnore will do the job.

Comment: @jokster - I don't want the enum to be a property of the Car class. I only want it to be an inner member.

Comment: OK. Since only properties (or fields) are serialized, any other inner member like an enum don't affect serialization.